# Search array for highest value, even if a tie

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
String [] nameArr = new String[10];
double [] totalArr = new double[10];
```

`nameArr` contains names of people, and `totalArr` contains the amounts those people raised in a fundraiser. I want to get the name of the person or persons who raised the most money. Some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
int winner = array_maximum(totalArr); //would return array element 0-9
//winner = 4 if totalArr[4] has the highest value
```

So I can then do something like:

```
String winPerson = nameArr[winner];
System.out.println(winPerson);
```

I'm sure the method to do this doesn't involve returning the array element number, but this is just a way I figure it could potentially work. Does there exist such a method in Java to do what I want? What if there is a tie?

Here's some rough work I did, still testing:

```
private String winner() {
    int i;
    double tentativeMaximum = totalArr[0];
    String winningPersons = nameArr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < totalArr.length; i++) {
        if (totalArr[i] > tentativeMaximum) {
            winningPersons = nameArr[i];
            tentativeMaximum = totalArr[i];
        } else if (totalArr[i] == tentativeMaximum) {
            winningPersons = winningPersons + " plus " + nameArr[i];
        }
    }
    winningPersons = winningPersons + " has won";
    return winningPersons;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do in case of a tie? There seem to be four possibilities: return the first one, return the last one, return an arbitrary one, or return a list of all tied names. (For the last, you'd probably design the method to always return a list, even if there are no ties.)

Comment: I'm not really sure. I want to be able to print all of the "winners" in case of a tie. I'm not sure how to go about it. `System.out.println("The winners are "+winner+...);`

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe a loop? Some conditions? Anything you can show us?

Comment: All it requires is a single loop. There are millions of code samples that find max and/or min of something in arrays.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi, I've appended code I'm working with now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all names corresponding to the maximum funds raised, you should design the method to always return a list. Here's one possibility:

```
List<String> bestFundraisers(String[] names, double[] totals) {
    final List<String> winners = new ArrayList<>();
    final int n = names.length;
    // optional: throw an exception if totals.length != n
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double raised = totals[i];
        if (raised >= max) {
            if (raised > max) {
                winners.clear();
                max = raised;
            }
            winners.add(names[i]);
        }
    }
    return winners;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For such a small array, the simplest solution is to find the maximum and take all the values which are the maximum.  This creates no objects.

```
public static void printBestFundraisers(String[] names, double[] totals) {
    double max = totals[0];
    for(double d: totals) 
        if(max < d)
            max = d;
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        if(totals[i] == max)
            System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend first creating a class called Person. Each person holds a string, name, and a number, their funds. In another class create a way to enter in all of the information to various Persons. Create an array of Persons and sort it by score. Use the persons high score and return their name.

Comment: Why create more classes when the original code already has arrays containing all the information?

Comment: @amdrew It is good programming practice to create objects and use them. Also the code would be a lot easier to understand.